# Add missing parenthesis to a given string

Tags: ruby

Currently I am facing one issue where I have add missing parenthesis into string. If there is an open parenthesis with no closing parenthesis, then we have to add closing parenthesis after the first found question mark or period.

Here is my code

```
def fix_para(input) 
  opening = input.count("(")
  closing = input.count(")")
  valid_str = ""
  input.split(//).each do |c|
    if c == "("
      opening = opening - 1
      valid_str << c
    elsif c == ")"
      closing = closing - 1
      valid_str << c
    elsif c == "?" || c == "."
      valid_str << c
      closing = closing - 1 if closing > 0
      valid_str << ")"
    else
      valid_str << c
    end
  end
  valid_str
end
```

This code works fine for the input string:

```
"(((Hey) how are you? how is it going."
```

but fails with:

```
"Hey how are you? (Is (your) name Larry?"
```

What I am missing?

Here are two sample strings with the expected output:

```
fix_para "Hey how are you? (Is (your) name Larry?"
  #=> "Hey how are you? (Is (your) name Larry?)"

fix_para "(((Hey) how are you? how is it going."
  #=> "(((Hey) how are you?) how is it going.)"
```

Comment: The problem is that your algorithm is flawed. You cannot start with a global count of the `(` and `)` characters, and assume that an additional `)` needs to be added as each sentence ends. It simply doesn't work.

Comment: What is the expected result for `"(((Hey) how are you? how is it going."` ""(((Hey) how are you?)) how is it going."" or `"(((Hey) how are you?) how is it going.)"`?

Comment: Have a more careful think about how the algorithm needs to work. What you've currently written will, as you've discovered, only handle a certain subset of examples. The other scenario you're not covering at all is: What if the string contains matching pairs of parentheses *and then* contains unmatched parentheses? For example: `"(This is a string.) (Your algorithm doesn't handle it well."`

Comment: The problem is at `closing = closing - 1 if closing > 0` and the assumption that it should append the closing parenthesis.

Comment: @spickermann I have updated my question with expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you need to keep track of the numbers of non-terminated left parentheses as you step through the characters of the string, left-to-right, a number that can increase or decrease. You could obtain the desired strings as follows.

```
def add_closing_parens(str)
  n = 0 
  s = str.each_char.with_object('') do |c,s|
    s << c
    case c
    when '('
      n += 1
    when ')'
      n -= 1
    when '?', '.', '!'
      if n > 0
        s << ')'
        n -= 1
      end
    end
  end
  n.zero? ? s : nil      
end
```

`n` is the number of left parens that have not yet been closed. I added the exclamation mark as it can terminate a sentence.

```
add_closing_parens "Hey how are you? (Is (your) name Larry?"
  #=> "Hey how are you?) (Is (your) name Larry?)" 
add_closing_parens "(((Hey) how are you? how is it going."
  #=> "(((Hey) how are you?) how is it going.)"
add_closing_parens "((Hey (how (are) you? What's happenin? Wow!"
  #=> "((Hey (how (are) you?) What's happenin?) Wow!)"
add_closing_parens "Hey how (are) you? (What's (happenin? Wow!"
  #=> "Hey how (are) you? (What's (happenin?) Wow!)"

str = "(((Hey (how (are) you? What's happenin? Wow!"
add_closing_parens str
  #=> nil
```

If you want to be able to add missing right parentheses at the end, replace the last two lines with:

```
end << ')' * n
```

after which:

```
add_closing_parens str
  #=> "(((Hey (how (are) you?) What's happenin?) Wow!))"
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to add the matching number of closing brackets to the end of the string, I think this will work:

```
def fix_para(input)
  opening = input.count("(")
  closing = input.count(")")
  return input unless opening > closing

  input + ')' * (opening - closing)
end
```

Comment: Silly errors. Thanks for highlighting them @CarySwoveland. I've editted my answer. I'll leave it there just in case people looking at this need the simpler solution.